# How to maintain connection between list item and database row?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, listview, android-intent

In my Android app I am using a listview of accounts (for a checkbook type app). I am pulling these accounts from a database and displaying them. My question is once I have the cursor object where I pull the information and display it in the list item, how can I maintain a connection between that list item and the id value of the row it came from?

The reason I would like to do this is because the accounts are displayed in a navigation drawer. When I select a list item, I want the main fragment to display more information for that account, including transactions for it. This is why I would like to maintain a relation to the id, so that I can link it to the transactions table.

I don't want to display the id value in the list item, because it would be useless to the user. What should I do here?

Comment: Rather than display the id value, give it a name, but keep the variable for the id value.

Comment: @BlackHatSamurai I'm not sure I understand. I'm reading the values from a Cursor, and populating UI elements. Are you saying I should read the id value and just store it as a global or class level variable of some sort?

Comment: Yes. That is exactly what I am saying.

Comment: So how would you recommend it used once I select the item? Should I map the list item position to the table id using a dictionary of some sort? I guess I could map the id to the account name, and when I select an item I can get that account name and find it that way, but it seems like a lot of work. I will play with that idea and let you know.

Comment: Personally, I'd create an object for each list item. That way you can store all the data in the object, and reference the DB when you need to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach would be to create an object for each of the list items. You could then populate the object with class level variables, like ID, Name, etc. This would only require one connection, and would keep the data you need through out the app.

Comment: Sorry I never came back to this, but thanks for the idea. Instead of using a CursorAdapter, I created an adapter of objects for the items being listed and I was able to package those into intents and  reference them in the other activities as needed.

Comment: @McAdam331 Glad I could help. Best of luck with your project.

Comment: The initial project (required for class) went great. The class loved it, we were the only group to develop in Android. I plan on reworking the app over my holiday break and making it even better, so I'll come back if I ever need more help.